# How to calculate the following fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do I calculate the fourier transform of $x^2 * e^{-x^2}$

If I let $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = e^{-x^2}$, my attempt has been to calculate the fourier transform of $f$ and $g$ seperately and plug them into the convolution theorem formula

$transform(f*g) = \sqrt{2\pi} * transform(f) * transform(g)$

Is this the correct way to go about it, am I using the convolution theorem correctly?

Comment: The problem is that the Fourier transform of $f $ only exists in the sense of tempered distributions.If you know about these, your idea will work. One thing about which I am not sure is if you are using the convolution theorem correctly, since you use the same symbol for multiplication and convolution.

Comment: @PhoemueX
I am not entirely sure about the use of symbols, I definately meant multiplication. That is to calculate the fourier transform of the product 
$x^2 e^{-x^2}$ can I calculate the fourier transform of each of those functions seperately and plug them into the formula given by the product

$\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot transform(f) \cdot transform(g)$  and get the fourier transform for $x^2 e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: I [answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447724/what-does-the-result-of-a-fourier-transform-mean-how-is-it-interpreted/1447783#1447783) yesterday a question concerning the Fourier transform, that contains the answer to this question. I think you might be interested in reading it, since you asked the question. Any feedback on the answer (comment, acceptance) would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @ArnoldDoveman: No, you have (up to multiplies of $2\pi $) that $F (fg)= F (f)\ast F (g) $, where $F $ is Fourier transform and $\ast $ is convolution.

Answer (score 1):

For any *good enough* function $\phi$ (like $e^{-x^2}$)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\phi(x)\,e^{ix\xi}\,dx=\frac1i\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,\frac{d}{d\xi}\,e^{ix\xi}\,dx=\frac1i\,\frac{d}{d\xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,e^{ix\xi}\,dx.
$$
Use twice.

Comment: ... or use the fact that $x^2\mathrm e^{-x^2}=\left.\partial_\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda x^2}\right\rvert_{\lambda=1}$